# tcbtheorem: Multiline centered title

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm using the `tcolorbox` package for creating an `algoritm` environment. Now, in one algorithm, my title text spans two lines, and I'd like to have it centered. However, the second line is only centered under the title, but not the part "Algorithm 1:". I'd like to have this centered as if "Algorithm 1" was part of the text, but I don't see how I could achieve this.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}%
{
colback = white,
colbacktitle = white,
coltitle = black,
center title,
fonttitle = \bfseries,
sharp corners,
boxrule = 1pt,
titlerule = 1pt,
width = 0.8\linewidth,
center
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}{This is a very long title that causes a break}{}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Algorithm 1: This is the optics that I'd like to have, with the second line centered. }
\end{center}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: above: the title as it is, below: how I'd like it]

Comment: I think you should not use `newtcbtheorem` for this but `\newtcolorbox` rather. The name for a theorem is set left (Algorithm) and is not part of the title here

Comment: Hmm...but this means that I can't keep the automatic numbering, does it? I'm using a numbering within chapters, so that I get Algorithm 1.1, Algorithm 1.2,... including the options for safely referencing the numbers.

Comment: `\newtcolorbox` allows for autonumbering

Comment: Ah, okay, then I'll go to the manual and check it! Thanks!

Comment: In fact,  I think you're misusing the bundle of `theorem name, number and description` like a caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` library for theorems does use the theorem title (`Algorithm` here) and fixes it to the left margin of the title. The real title (called 'description' is independent of this, so `center title` will only center the description but not the number and name of the environment.

Using a `\newtcolorbox` this can be fixed and almost the same features of the `\newtcbtheorem` command can be achieved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{algorithm}[3][]{%
colback = white,
colbacktitle = white,
coltitle = black,
center title,
fonttitle = \bfseries,
sharp corners,
boxrule = 1pt,
titlerule = 1pt,
width = 0.8\linewidth,
center,
title={Algorithm \thetcbcounter: #2},
label={#3},
#1
}

\begin{document}

See the nice Algorithm \ref{firstalgo}

\begin{algorithm}{This is a very long title that causes a break}{firstalgo}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Algorithm 1: This is the optics that I'd like to have, with the second line centered. }
\end{center}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]